# Can't connect to Windows (SMB)

Tags: windows-7, osx-mountain-lion, macbook-pro, file-sharing, smb

I have a MacBook Pro (OS X 10.8.4) and a Windows 7 Ultimate machine. I can't connect to the latter because of incorrect password or login. I tried to create several users on Windows machine and even created quest user and it also does not work. On the Windows machine:

- network discovery turned on
- file and printer sharing turned on
- public sharing turned on
- firewall switched off

Also I can connect to Filezilla's FTP server and RDC Mac client works fine but SMB doesn't want to work at all.

Comment: it took me some time to figure out that MBP meant Mac Book Pro.

Comment: not sure how MACs do samba, but from a linux perspective, one important step is to make sure both systems allow the same authentication protocol. I recommend NTLMv2 or better. in smb.conf, its 'client auth NTLMv2 auth = yes'